# Grafana & Loki along with ECS

Tags: grafana, amazon-ecs, grafana-loki

Is it possible to implement log parsing and filtering using Grafana and Loki (with FluentBit) on AWS ECS? I am following [this documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/aws/ecs/) and it seemingly binds the labels set on the application container with the fluentbit container via awsfirelens. In that scenario, I can't seem to implement fluentbit parsing or filtering.

Is there a different way to go so that I can define labels for each ECS service (w/ ECS metadata) that is then shipped to Grafana? Ideally, I would have one ECS container per EC2 instance that could scrape these logs and ship them to Loki/Grafana (while keeping the service specific labels in tact).